# Antivirus Issues

Tags: antivirus

I have Ubuntu together with Window 8 installed on my laptop. I have installed Kaspersky Antivirus inside.

Do I need to install any new antivirus program? Any advice for the more efficient anti virus program?

Comment: What do you want to protect? Ubuntu or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't need an antivirus for Ubuntu/Linux. I'm assuming you've installed Kaspersky on your Windows. In Ubuntu viruses don't spread like in Windows, even if any they won't do harm to the system maybe infect some Wine (Emulated WinXP) files if you have it installed. Though the last possibility browser cookies, in conclusion for this all ClamAV would be enough. To install ClamAV:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamav
sudo freshclam
```

Then perform a Home Directory scan for example:

```
clamscan -rio ~/
```

More detailed on [ClamAV](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV).